# Why can't I target the image element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add jQuery to work with my web site and this is my first excursion into jQuery. For some reason, I just can't get it to work and I am unsure of why. There are no errors in the debug output. Here is the exact code I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#Preview1').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#Image1").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
        alert("triggered");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="file" id="#Image1">
<img src="#" id="Preview1">
</form>
</html>
```

It works on jsfidle, but not when I try it in chrome or firefox. All of the answers I have seen so far are something simple like, put it inside a document.ready function or you are missing a semicolon or mistyped the URL. If I have this, I am just not spotting it. It also does not work with the latest version of jQuery from google.

Comment: Why would you use JQuery 1.2.6. ?

Comment: We don't really care if the latest jQuery will HELP - we just want to cut ourselves seeing you using something that old.

Comment: Have no fear, I am using a newer version. I was getting an error in the javascript console and did this as a troubleshooting step. I'm using jQuery 1.9.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `#` from `id` attribute of `input`

Change

```
 <input type="file" id="#Image1">
```

To

```
 <input type="file" id="Image1">
```

### OR

Use `\\` to escape `#`

```
 $("#\\#Image1").change(function () {
    alert("triggered");
 });
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aGB9C/)

From [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

Comment: Oh. Duh. That did it. Thanks. I was so worried about having done something wrong in my jQeury code that I totally missed this in the HTML. Thanks.